# PHP Code inside PHP Variable

Tags: php, oracle

I have a question regarding integrating PHP code inside a PHP Variable.
I am doing report for PHP to PDF and I am using PHP to PDF

I want to query tables from ORACLE DB and print it to PDF and now I am having problem with escape character and stuff

my code is like this,

```
$compProfileSql = "SELECT * FROM DRAWING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :PROJNAME"
$compProfileParse = oci_parse($conn, $compProfileSql);
                        oci_bind_by_name($compProfileParse, ":PROJNAME", $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']);
                        oci_execute($compProfileParse);

$content = "
<table class=\"table table-bordered\">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>PROJECT NAME</th>
                        <th>COMPONENT</th>
                        <th>DRAWING</th>                           
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>               
                    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($compProfileParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false){
                        <tr>
                            <td>$row[COMP_TYPE]</td>
                            <td>$row[JML_DWG]</td>
                            <td>$row[JML_MARKING]</td>                                                                      
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
";
```

I couldnt see the table working in the generated PDF. Am i making mistake with the escape character ?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate it:

```
$content = "
<table class=\"table table-bordered\">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PROJECT NAME</th>
                    <th>COMPONENT</th>
                    <th>DRAWING</th>                           
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";               
                while (($row = oci_fetch_array($compProfileParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false){
                    $content .= "<tr>
                        <td>" . $row['COMP_TYPE'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['JML_DWG'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['JML_MARKING'] . "</td>                                                                      
                    </tr>";
                }
           $content .= "</tbody>
        </table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also write as follows,

```
$content = "  
         <table class=\"table table-bordered\">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PROJECT NAME</th>
                    <th>COMPONENT</th>
                    <th>DRAWING</th>                           
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";               
                while (($row = oci_fetch_array($compProfileParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false){
                    $content .= "<tr>
                        <td>$row[COMP_TYPE]</td>
                        <td>$row[JML_DWG]</td>
                        <td>$row[JML_MARKING]</td>                                                                      
                    </tr>";
                }
            $content .= "</tbody>
        </table>  
";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes instead of double qoutes then you will not required to use escape characters anymore.

```
    $content = '
    <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PROJECT NAME</th>
                            <th>COMPONENT</th>
                            <th>DRAWING</th>                           
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';    

                    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($compProfileParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false){ 
                    $content.=  '<tr>
                                <td>'.$row["COMP_TYPE"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["JML_DWG"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["JML_MARKING"].'</td>               
                            </tr>';
                        }
                    $content.= '</tbody>
                    </table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Would add this as a comment, but you won't be able to see much of it, so...

What I can tell first is that you don't differentiate HTML and PHP, try it like this:

```
$content = "
<table class=\"table table-bordered\">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PROJECT NAME</th>
                    <th>COMPONENT</th>
                    <th>DRAWING</th>                           
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>  <?php             
                while (($row = oci_fetch_array($compProfileParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row[COMP_TYPE]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row[JML_DWG]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row[JML_MARKING]; ?></td>                                                                      
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>";
```

Even though I am not sure about the methods you are using to print to PHP, if this is going to be treated as a simple string and not converted to HTML anywhere, you will just see the code and nothing else.